# Abelian Category of Pro-Objects

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category and consider the category of pro-objects $\text{Pro}(\mathcal{A})$. Objects in this category may be presented as filtered projective system $(A_i)_{i\in I}$. This category is also abelian, however, it is not clear to me what short exact sequences look like, that is if
$$0\to (A_i)_{i\in I}\to (B_i)_{i\in I}\to (C_i)_{i\in I}\to 0$$
is a short exact sequence in $\text{Pro}(\mathcal{A})$, what does this mean for the morphisms $A_i\to B_i \to C_i$? In particular, if $A_i\to B_i$ is filtered system of morphisms in $\mathcal{A}$, then what is the cokernel of $(A_i)_{i\in I}\to (B_i)_{i\in I}$?

Comment: Why is ${\rm Pro}(\mathcal{A})$ abelian in the first place?